# How to include localized jquery datepicker in your project

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui

The problem is how to include the needed files for a jquery datepicker for say someone in Sweeden or Russia so this code works as expected.

```
  var browserLang = $('#browserLanguage').val(); //this value is set on serverside
         if (browserLang !="en-ca" && browserLang != "fr-ch" && browserLang !="en-gb" && browserLang !="pt-br" && browserLang !="zh-cn" && browserLang != "zh-hk" && browserLang != "zh-tw" )
            browserLang = browserLang.substring(0,2);


       if (browserLang!= "en") 
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[browserLang]);
```

btw: taking 1st 2 of fr-ca and en-ca since they don't appear to be supported with any files downloaded from jquery UI site and in folder \development-bundle\ui\i18n\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the problem?

```
(browserLang == "fr-ca" && browserLang =="en-ca" )
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
(browserLang === "fr-ca" || browserLang === "en-ca")
```

(added `===` because [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) is in my brain, but check out the `||`)

**Update**

After you updated your question, the first conditional still doesn't look right.  In its current form, it's basically:  "If browserLang ***is not*** equal to any of these, remove all but the first two characters."

In reality, I bet you mean to say "If browserLang ***IS*** equal to any of these, remove all but the first two characters."  In which case you should use the `||` operator in conjunction with `===`, not the `&&` operator.

Comment: I corrected the code.  I am meaning to only take the first 2 of the ones that are included in the download